# Define border around 2D array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, border

I have an array:

```
Cell[][] cells = new Cell[width+2][height+2];
```

Which is filled according to a certain input:

```
for (int i = 1; i < cells.length-1; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j < cells[i].length-1; j++) {
      if (certain input) {
      cells[i][j] = new Cell(true);
    } else {
      cells[i][j] = new Cell(false);
    } 
 }
}
```

Now I still need to define the border cells which need to become false. I tried this with another for loop but somehow this does not seem to work. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? So is it not going to else block?

Comment: what do you mean by border cell. are you trying to set the first index to false?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I understand you, but if you want to make a frame for the true cells you should do something like:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++) {
        if (i== 0 || i == cells.length-1 || j== 0 || j == cells.length-1) {
          cells[i][j] = new Cell(false);
        } 
     }
    }
```